# Finish Operation before Starting Another One

Tags: angular

I have a component and in the `ngOnInit()`-method I call a function that loads a JSON from a server and saves the data in a local variable, and in the next line I read out the local variable and operate with it.

Here's the code:

```
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {

    private tasksJSON = {};



    constructor(private router: Router, private variables: Variables, private apiService: ApiService) {
        if (!this.variables.getIsLoggedIn()) {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getTasks();
        console.log("log 1:" + JSON.stringify(this.tasksJSON));
        let tasks = this.tasksJSON.tasks;
        this.tasksJSON = Object.keys(tasks).map(function(k) { return tasks[k] });
        console.log("log 2:" + this.tasksJSON);
    }

    getTasks() {
        this.apiService.getTasks().
            subscribe(
            data => this.tasksJSON = data,
            //error => this.error = <any>error,
            error => this.variables.setFailure(error),
            () => console.log('log getTasks():' + JSON.stringify(this.tasksJSON)
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that apparently the data isn't loaded when the `let tasks = this.tasksJSON.tasks;` begins, so I get an error.

The log looks like:

```
log 1:{}
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
log getTasks():{"tasks":{"epg":[{"name":"EPGStart"},{"name":"EPGStop"},{"name":"AutoTimer"},{"name":"CleanupDB"},{"name":"RefreshDB"},{"name":"ClearRecordingStats"},{"name":"CleanupRefreshDB"}],"media":[{"name":"UpdateVideoDB"},{"name":"RebuildVideoDB"},{"name":"RebuildAudioDB"},{"name":"RebuildPhotoDB"},{"name":"ClearAudioStats"},{"name":"ClearVideoStats"},{"name":"ClearPhotoStats"}],"system":[{"name":"Hibernate"},{"name":"Standby"},{"name":"Shutdown"}]}}
```

The apiService looks like this:

```
export class ApiService {

private localURL = '../app/apiFiles/';
getTasks() {
        return this.http.get(this.localURL + 'tasks.json')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

How can in solve, that the `let tasks = this.tasksJSON.tasks;` starts, when the data is finished loading?

Edit: Added the api-Service

Comment: You need to do those things in the callbacks to the subscription, this is the very basis of async programming. Alternatively, return a subscribable or promise to further operate on.

Answer (score 0):

your getTasks() method should return a promise.

Then you can do ...

```
this.getTasks().then((returnValueOfGetTasks) => {
    // Following code needs changing to use returnValueOfGetTasks
    console.log("log 1:" + JSON.stringify(this.tasksJSON));
    let tasks = this.tasksJSON.tasks;
    this.tasksJSON = Object.keys(tasks).map(function(k) { return tasks[k] });
    console.log("log 2:" + this.tasksJSON);
}).catch((err) => {
    // todo: handle err
});
```

The then method will be called when the promise is resolved.

You can either use promises or Observables as provided by RxJS.

Observables are basically streams of promises. e.g. The observable subscribe method is similar to a promise then method but a subscribe method can be called many times, each time the stream emits.

Today this is bog standard async JS programming. async programming is basically handling things that do not happen instantly. e.g. HTTP requests take time to respond.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Above i added my implemented apiService...
Maybe you can look at this...?

And the `this.getTasks().then(...)` is the call in the `ngOnInit()` ?
Or the separated method `getTasks()`?

Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: you are not returning anything from getTasks. You need to do ... return this.apiService.getTasks() - that will return the observable / promise you need

Comment: you prob also need to return something in your subscribe block (in addition to returning the observable).

Comment: couldn´t i do the handling of the observable directly in the `getTasks()`-function?
Something like `this.apiService.getTasks().then(...)`?
Do you have a solution for this?
I do not want to do this in the ngOnInit function... :/

Maybe i could have in `ngOnInit` just `this.getTasks` and the rest in the `getTasks()`... ?

Comment: you typically put the HTTP stuff in a service. So your getTasks method will go in a service and it returns an observable which is handled (with subscribe()) inside the component class.  this allows the response to be handled differently in different components. You just inject the service into your component when you want to use it.